# How to find settings for ede-cpp-root-projects in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, cedet

In Emacs, we can set `ede-cpp-root-project` as follows:

```lisp
(ede-cpp-root-project "NAME"
                      :file "FILENAME"
                      :include-path '("/include" "../include" "/c/include")
                      :system-include-path '("/usr/include/c++/3.2.2/")
                      :spp-table '(("MOOSE" . "")
                                   ("CONST" . "const")))
```

Once set, how can we verify the value of `:include-path`, `:system-include-path` and `:spp-table`? I want to see if EDE/Emacs has set other values apart from what I have specified. If so, I'd like to know what those values are.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens when you evaluate `(get 'ede-cpp-root-project 'include-path)`?

Comment: OK, that's not the way to go then...

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be in a C or C++ buffer you can use:

M-x semantic-c-describe-environment RET

and look for the EDE project associated with your buffer, and the data it shows should include your different paths and all the macros it is using.

If you are not in a C buffer, you need to use some other debugging tools.  When I debug these features, I use `data-debug` which is part of the CEDET distribution when you use it from bzr.

```
(require 'data-debug)
```

Next:

```
M-: ede-object RET
```

will eval the variable `ede-object`, and data-debug will give you a readable dump of what is there.  Use SPC to expand sections.

If `M-:` wasn't property taken over, use

```
M-x data-debug-eval-expression RET ede-object RET
```

and if you dont' have data debug, you can just try to interpret the raw object dump from the 'eval'.